# How to name a image attachment in lettre builder?

Tags: email, rust, gmail, html-email, email-attachments

Get this, I'm creating a simple script in Rust to trigger and send an email with a image attached in mail body.

Here's the code:

HTML markup:

```
<p>
   <img id='usd' title='usd-today' alt='usd_brl' name='usd-today' style='width: 450px; height: 340px;' src=cid:monthly-charge />
<p>
```

Lettre mail builder:

```
let email = Message::builder()
        .mailbox(to_header)
        .from(email_sender.parse().unwrap())
        .subject(subject) 
        .multipart(
            MultiPart::mixed().multipart(
                MultiPart::related()
                    .singlepart(SinglePart::html(String::from(body)))
                    .singlepart(
                        Attachment::new_inline(String::from("monthly-charge"))
                            .body(image_body, "image/png".parse().unwrap()),
                    ),
            ),
        )?;
```

So, everything is working fine and the attachment as well.

But, just for curiosity and learning purposes, when I receive the email using gmail specifically (tried to see something en outlook but didn't found it), the attached image shows as "noname" in it.

Check:
[gmail image attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYHVu.png)

So, I wonder if the problem is when we attach the image to the body using singlepart method in the builder. I searched for some information in the docs, but didn't found anything. Nothing related to attachment options, name and so on. At least, nothing that I saw... forgive me if the answer is in the docs...

Anyway, someone have a hint or an idea of what can be done here?

I tried to name it the image html tag, put alt and also title but nothing changed. Also tried to put an id into it, but nothing.
Tried to send to different email providers.

Comment: What's the difference between [`Attachment::new()`](https://docs.rs/lettre/latest/lettre/message/struct.Attachment.html#method.new) and [`Attachment::new_inline()`](https://docs.rs/lettre/latest/lettre/message/struct.Attachment.html#method.new_inline)?

Comment: If you're sending from a domain with no reputation for clean emails, you may also have some trouble being flagged as spam. Check the spam folder for your various recipient accounts if you feel like they haven't received something they should have.